# Why does this java.lang.IllegalStateException happen, when I use playframework to response a chunked akka source?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

When I use playframework to response a mp3 audio. I want to use the chunked transceiver. Then I make a akka source in akka stream to response. And use the play Ok.chunked resule. But it has a Exception.

The play version is 2.5.18. And the akka-stream version is 2.4.20.
The Exception is:

```
[ERROR 2023-08-02 00:13:13,223] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-32 c.x.a.c.DefaultErrorHandler] - A server error occurred for speech-staging.ai.srv:speech-staging.ai
.srv/stream_audio_v2,from: 10.38.162.91
play.core.server.common.ServerResultException: Error converting Play Result for server backend
        at play.core.server.common.ServerResultUtils$.play$core$server$common$ServerResultUtils$$handleConversionError$1(ServerResultUtils.scala:108)
        at play.core.server.common.ServerResultUtils$.resultConversionWithErrorHandling(ServerResultUtils.scala:129)
        at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion.convertResult(NettyModelConversion.scala:251)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayRequestHandler$$handleAction$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(PlayRequestHandl
er.scala:273)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayRequestHandler$$handleAction$2$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(PlayRequestHandl
er.scala:267)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:253)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:157)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Future.scala:256)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Future.scala:256)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise.onComplete(Promise.scala:337)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:256)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:256)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: internal error
        at akka.stream.impl.VirtualPublisher.registerPublisher(StreamLayout.scala:832)
        at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.akka$stream$impl$MaterializerSession$$doSubscribe(StreamLayout.scala:1034)
        at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materialize$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(StreamLayout.scala:925)
        at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materialize$3$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(StreamLayout.scala:924)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materialize$3.apply(StreamLayout.scala:924)
        at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materialize$3.apply(StreamLayout.scala:924)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.materialize(StreamLayout.scala:924)
        at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl.materialize(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:256)
        at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl.materialize(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:146)
        at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:350)
        at akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.runWith(Source.scala:81)
        at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion.play$core$server$netty$NettyModelConversion$$createChunkedResponse(NettyModelConversion.scala:272)
        at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion$$anonfun$convertResult$1.apply(NettyModelConversion.scala:205)
        at play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion$$anonfun$convertResult$1.apply(NettyModelConversion.scala:182)
        at play.core.server.common.ServerResultUtils$.resultConversionWithErrorHandling(ServerResultUtils.scala:127)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

And my code is:

```
class StreamTest @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {
    def stream_audio_v2(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { req =>
        val source = Source.actorRef[ByteString](10000, OverflowStrategy.fail).mapMaterializedValue { sourceActor =>
            val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new StreamActor(sourceActor)).withDispatcher("assist-dispatcher"))
            actor ! "stream_audio_v2"
        }

        Future.successful(Ok.chunked(source).as("audio/mp3"))
    }
}
```

```
class StreamActor(outActor: ActorRef = null) extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {

        case "stream_audio_v2" =>
            log.info("receive stream_audio_v2")
            val out = outActor

            log.info("out put streamProducer.stream")

            Future {
                val source = StreamActor.getSource()
                var buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
                var length = 0
                while (length != -1) {
                    length = source.read(buffer)
                    out ! ByteString(buffer.clone())
                    Thread.sleep(1)
                }
                source.close()
                out ! akka.actor.Status.Success(())
            }

}
```

I tried to use stream to instead of chunked, but it is not useful.

```
    def stream_audio_v2_5(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { req =>
        val source = Source.actorRef[ByteString](10000, OverflowStrategy.fail).mapMaterializedValue { sourceActor =>
            val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new StreamActor(sourceActor)).withDispatcher("assist-dispatcher"))
            actor ! "stream_audio_v2"
        }

        Future.successful(Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(source, None, Some("audio/mp3"))))
    }
```

It has same Exception.

I am really hope you will help me, thanks.

Comment: The error doesn't provide enough details to understand the problem. Could be that you are intercepting the error in some place (maybe a filter or action) and accidentally hiding the error that tells you what's the problem?

Comment: Have you checked [Sending large amounts of data](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream#Sending-large-amounts-of-data) or [Chunked Responses]https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream#Chunked-responses)? You can use `FileIO.fromPath(path)` if the file is in the server or you have using a `URL` or using `StreamConverters.fromInputStream(data)` in case you have an `InputStream`

Comment: Same as Gaston, the error is not really helpful but do you really need the actor stuff? The purpose of Akka Stream and Play is somehow to hide actors so that you can use higher abstractions.

Comment: Those are really old versions of Play Framework and Akka. You might want to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, bros.

I find the problem. It is `.withDispatcher("assist-dispatcher")`, but I haven't disposes this in play `appliaction.conf`.

```
assist-dispatcher {
  type = "Dispatcher"
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 10
    # Allow core threads to time out
    allow-core-timeout = off
  }
  throughput = 100
}
```

It is a stupid problem. I am really sorry for wasting your time.